# Global variable use in third activity

Tags: android

`AnimationDrawable animation;` use in `Frame by Frame animation`. i have use it this way ::

```
try {
               ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.girl_anim);
               animation = new AnimationDrawable();
               new xyz().execute();
                animation.setOneShot(false);
               img.setBackgroundDrawable(animation);
               img.post(new Starter());
           } catch (Exception e) {
            }
```

**external class ::**

```
  private class xyz extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
            //private final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(tranning.this);

            protected void onPreExecute() {
                /*this.dialog.setMessage("Please Wait...");
                this.dialog.show();
                */

            }

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

                try {
                    for(int i = 1;i<54;i++)
                    {
                    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream) new URL(
                    "http://test/MRESC/images/test/girl/"+"girl000"+i+".png")
                    .getContent());
                    Drawable frame =new BitmapDrawable(bitmap);
                    animation.addFrame(frame, 50);
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {

                }

                return null;
            }

            protected void onPostExecute(final Void unused) {
                //if (this.dialog.isShowing()) {
                //  this.dialog.dismiss();

                //}

            }
        }
    class Starter implements Runnable {

        public void run() {
            animation.start();        
        }


    }
```

now this code used in third activity.but problem is that i want it at creation on first activity, so how can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either make the variable static, or you can just pass it as a parameter between the activities(putExtra), but because you use this in a async task, you might have to use a runnable:

```
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
//do something with a variable from the activity
}
}, 100);
```

Also declare the handler in the activity:

```
private final Handler handler = new Handler();
```